# Add Proxy to restlet ClientRessource

Tags: restlet

I am trying to add proxy settings to a Java Swing client app, which connects and gets data over https from an external server. However the ClientResource (restlet:2.4.0) ignores all efforts with parameters and connects directly to the url? If the syntax is correct, what are the correct parameters?
Further, how can I use system proxy settings?

```
private static ClientResource getClientResource(String url) {

    ClientResource clientResource = null;

    try {
        // test
        Client client = new Client(new Context(), Protocol.HTTPS);
        client.getContext().getParameters().add("https.proxyHost", "PROXY_IP");
        client.getContext().getParameters().add("https.proxyPort", "PROXY_PORT");

        clientResource = new ClientResource(url);

        // test
        clientResource.setNext(client);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return clientResource;
}


private static Response sendGetRequest(String url) {
    ClientResource resource = getClientResource(BASE_URL + url);

    try {
        resource.get();
    } catch (ResourceException e){
        e.printStackStrace();
        return null;
    }
    return getResponse();
}
```

EDIT added compiles:

```
compile 'org.restlet.jse:org.restlet:2.3.12'
compile 'org.restlet.jse:org.restlet.ext.jackson:2.3.12'
// switch to Apache Http Client, enable proxy'
compile 'org.restlet.jse:org.restlet.ext.httpclient:2.3.12' 
// httpClient for Class Definitions
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3'
```

CURRENT EXCEPTION:

```
Starting the Apache HTTP client
An error occurred during the communication with the remote HTTP server.

org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:867)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.internal.HttpMethodCall.sendRequest(HttpMethodCall.java:339)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.commit(ClientAdapter.java:105)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:119)
    at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:153)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is only supported with the `httpClient` extension, that relies on the Apache HTTP client library (maven artifact id: `org.restlet.ext.httpclient`).

You can then either use the system environment properties: `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort`, or set these parameters on the client instance (as you did, but names are distinct and documented [here](https://restlet.com/open-source/documentation/javadocs/2.3/jse/ext/org/restlet/ext/httpclient/HttpClientHelper.html) ).

```
Client client = new Client(new Context(), Protocol.HTTPS);
client.getContext().getParameters().add("proxyHost", "PROXY_IP");
client.getContext().getParameters().add("proxyPort", "PROXY_PORT");
```